# O que é uma 3rd Party e qual a sua importância para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos tradicionais?

Tags: terminologia

Embora exista uma definição na [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenvolvedora_de_terceiros), na maioria das vezes, este termo está co-relacionado a desenvolvimento de jogos. Devido a forma específica que o termo é tratado, surge a dúvida se esse conceito é aplicado a desenvolvimento de software tradicional ou aplicativos que não são jogos. Acredito que uma elucidação mais genérica, e menos específica a um ramo pode ajudar a esclarecer mais pessoas sobre esse termo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[3rd party ou Third-party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_software_component) nada mais é que o uso de componentes de terceiros, ou seja, algum software ou lib que outra pessoa criou, e que possa auxiliar no seu desenvolvimento.

Comment: Então não se refere a desenvolvedora, mas a prática do uso de software de terceiros?

Comment: Acredito que sim.

Comment: Se uma desenvolvedora, usa um motor, o unreal, ou se usa um framework ou até mesmo um CMS, está dentro do conceito de Third-party  ?

Comment: Sim, até mesmo algum sistema criado pela propria desenvolvedora, mas usado em outro projeto pode ser chamado de third-party system.

Eu trabalho em um e-commerce, e possuimos algumas libs compartilhadas entre os projetos, então podemos considerar que essas libs não sejam partes do sistema ao qual desenvolvemos.

Comment: É interessante pesquisar sobre o conceito de "acoplamento" para compreender melhor o uso de um third-party... Mas resumidamente, seu sistema deve apenas fazer uso de determinada tecnologia, e não depender dela. Em outras palavras, se você usa a unreal engine, vc deve ser capaz de desenvolver o mesmo jogo em um unity 3d por exemplo.