# O que significa vendor?

Tags: aplicação-web, diretório

Uma pasta com nome `vendor` é comumente usada em projetos web. Veja alguns exemplos: [rklet](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/rktlet), [ytd](https://github.com/Ch3ck/ytd).

Qual é o propósito e a importância dessa pasta? Por que ela tem esse nome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade, o diretório `vendor` está relacionado a aplicações desenvolvido por terceiros que compõem os requisitos da sua aplicação.

[O que é uma 3rd Party e qual a sua importância para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos tradicionais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215597/5878)

Este diretório não tem relação direta com o Laravel, como comentado na outra resposta. Em projetos PHP esse diretório é bastante comum pois é o diretório em que o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), gerenciador de dependências em PHP, utiliza para organizar os códigos de terceiros.

O primeiro projeto como exemplo, [rktlet](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/rktlet), utiliza o sistema de gerenciamento de pacotes [Glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), que também define o diretório `vendor` para armazenar as dependências. O segundo projeto, [ytd](https://github.com/Ch3ck/ytd), parece não utilizar nenhum sistema de gerenciamento, mas mesmo assim utiliza o diretório `vendor` por opção, seguindo costumes da própria comunidade.

Resumindo, o diretório `vendor` **geralmente** armazena dependências do projeto desenvolvido por terceiros - é assim que grande parte dos gerenciadores de pacotes trabalham - mas não há garantias disso. Projetos podem existir utilizando o diretório `vendor` mesmo que este não tenha nenhuma relação com as dependências. Eu posso muito bem armazenar meus arquivos JavaScript de minha página em um diretório `vendor`. Funciona, só pode ficar um confuso e, por isso, tal prática não é encorajada.

Comment: Legal. Pode esclarecer mais uma dúvida? Faz sentido dar commit na pasta `vendor` vez que o arquivo packages.json já descreve as dependências necessárias que podem ser instaladas utilizando o gerenciador de pacotes? Por exemplo, com o packages.json na pasta é só executar o `npm install`, no caso desse gerenciador.

Comment: Então, se está utilizando um gerenciador de pacotes, não faz sentido. Como o próprio arquivo já descreve todas as dependências, não "commitar" o diretório `vendor` reduz bastante o *payload* da aplicação.